# Librosa specshow, what data processing is done under the hood compared to plt.imshow

Tags: python, pytorch, librosa, torchvision

I am trying to understand, why a plot produced by `plt.imshow()` is way less detailed and more blurry, than a plot produced by `librosa.display.specshow`.

As the plots, or better to say, the data behind the plots is my basis of further analysis, I would like to go for as much detail as possible. Thus I wonder, what kind of black magic / enchancement / processing is done by `librosa` behind the curtains.

[image]
As you can see in the screenshot, I use the same array as well as the same figure size and resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blurry effect is likely to be a consequence of interpolation done by `plt.imshow`. Default value for `interpolation` parameter in this function is `antialiased`, you can turn it off by using `interpolation="none"` in `plt.imshow`. You can also change the default behavior of `plt.imshow` according to [Matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlibrc-sample).

To conclude, it is not that librosa does black magic but more matplotlib that blurs the image, which could be an interesting feature for real-world images, but degrades the quality when trying to look at data such as spectrograms.

Comment: Just a small correction for the generations to come:

use interpolation="nearest" to produce the desired results.